# Is it possible to display pdf using streambuilder in flutter through firestore database?

Tags: flutter

[Firestore document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sr6Q3.jpg)[My code using streambuilder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9sHp.jpg)

Comment: I dont want to create but display those pdf files which are already in firebase firestore ...i uses streambuilder to display the list of data and on clicking each data i want to display pdf files ..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In my flutter application, i want to display lists of pdf which i have stored in firebase . Is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of firestore you can put the pdf on Storage and read it from flutter app.
Try to follow this doc.
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage